# eye teeth - what do the words mean here?

Tags: phrase-usage

The speaker appears to mean "any things that are rotten and useless" by  "their dead granny’s **eye teeth**."

What does "their dead granny’s **eye teeth**" mean?

> Such political organizations are lower than a snake’s belly, and would all sell their dead granny’s **eye teeth**.

> Source: Online forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Eye tooth" is another name for upper canines, the pointy teeth we all have. They are among our most-used teeth, and so "give one's eye-teeth for" means to give something that is very precious.

So one could possibly say "I would give my eye-teeth for that opportunity".

But a normal caring person would not sell their grandmother's precious things for personal gain. Only a vile person with no ethics would try to sell their grandmother's valued items, and the writer is using that as a way of saying those political organizations have no morals and would do anything (possibly for money).

Comment: Also, 'sell one's own grandmother' is a metaphor for being willing to do anything for money, so this expression is combining the two.